# Nodejs Steam bot, Promise for loo

Tags: node.js, promise, steam

I made a little function returning me 2 numbers(prices) with promise.
I got the numbers by using a for loop, but when i run the code, it only prints 1 of the prices to the console.

function:

```
function getPrices(offer){
var price = [];
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    for(var i = 0; i < offer.length;i++){
        market.getItemPrice(730, offer[i].market_hash_name, function(err, data) {
            if(!err) {
                    try {
                            // JSON.parse() can throw an exception if not 
                            resolve(data.lowest_price.match(/\$(\d+\.\d+)/)[1]);
                    } catch(e) {
                            reject(e);
                    }
                    //price += data.lowest_price.match(/\$(\d+\.\d+)/)[1];
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

get the values:

```
getPrices(offer.itemsToReceive).then(function(val){
    var a = "";
    a += val;
    console.log(a);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

It only prints out one of the values:
0.05

Answer (score -1):

You are resolving the promise on the first iteration through the loop. You'll need to check if you are dealing with the last item, and only then resolve.